# Problems with string

Tags: c++, compare, cstring

Im working with a cstring function that is supposed to compare the values of two strings, MyString and m2. I have #include  so its definitely not that. these are my errors.

```
(74) : error C2275: 'MyString' : illegal use of this type as an expression
(74) : error C2660: 'MyString::length' : function does not take 1 arguments
(76) : error C2275: 'MyString' : illegal use of this type as an expression
```

and this is the code that I am getting them from.

```
bool MyString::operator ==(const MyString &m2) const
{
    int temp = 0;

    if (length(MyString) = length(m2)) // 74
    {
        if (strcmp(MyString, m2))  // 76
        {
            temp = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = 2;
        }
    }
    if(temp = 2)
    {
        return "true";
    }
    else
    {
        return "false";
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Lots of jumping in without thinking going on here - post more code please to clarify things. Specifically, post the declaration for MyString.

Comment: Is it your MyString class? I suppose it has 'operator char*'. And function length takes const MyString& as parameter. Correct?

Comment: Nearly every line has an error of some kind, none of which are related to the question, and the crux of the question (the length() function and the MyString class definition) are not given.  -1 for extremely unclear question.

Comment: Need the basic definition of MyString. Is length() really a function and not a method?

Comment: frankly, as another guy said, that code is a mess :)

Comment: Why was the question downvoted? It is not clearly stated and can be improved, but it is a problem I have seen others ask before (other places) and I am sure others will value the answers

Comment: "Problems with string" isn't a question. It's not really clear exactly what the question is, beyond the fact that there are a lot of elementary mistakes (which have been well corrected in the answers).

Answer (score 9):

**Problems:**

- Return true or false, not "true" or "false"
- You are doing compares with = instead of == (You use = for comparison twice in your code)
- To refer to yourself in a C++ class, you need to use the keyword *this* not the class name.
- Line 74 should be:

  ```
  if (length() == m2.length()) // 74
  ```
- strcmp takes a char* not a MyString.
- Line 76 should be:

  ```
  if (strcmp(this->c_str(), m2.c_str()))  // 76
  ```

In line 76 this assumes that the type MyString has a function c_str() that returns a pointer to a char[] buffer that is zero terminated.

---

**Structure of function:**

The structure of the function is really bad.  Consider something more like this:

```
bool MyString::operator ==(const MyString &m2) const
{
    if(this->length() != m2.length())
      return false;

    return !strcmp(this->c_str(), m2.c_str()));
}
```

Note: In the above functions this-> can be omitted.

Comment: Don't you think MyString has 'operator char*'?

Comment: If it did, I'd count that as one of the problems. Implicit conversions are generally best avoided

Comment: Or even return length() == m2.length() && strcmp(chars(), m2.chars()) == 0 . What a mess of a question!

Comment: @Mykola Golubyev if that was the case he probably would have used strlen above as well.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the problems have already been addressed. I just have a suggestion that has not been written above:

Use the free function form of the comparison operator instead of the member function:

```
bool operator == (MyString const &, MyString const &);
```

You will have to declare it as a friend if it depends on private data/members but you will get symmetry for the callers. Assuming that (as with std::string) you do have a implicit conversion defined from `const char *` to your string then the member function implementation of == is not symmetric. Member functions require the left hand side to be of the required type. The compiler will not perform conversions on the left hand side of the comparison:

```
// assumes MyString( const char* ) is defined and not explicit
// operator== defined as member function

const char* literal = "hola";
MyString str( "hola" );

if ( str == literal ) {} // correct
if ( literal == str ) {} // compilation error
```

If you implement as a member function, in the first test the compiler will create an unnamed MyString and call the conversion operator. In the second check, the compiler is not allowed to convert `literal` into a MyString, so it will never find your `operator==` implementation.

If you provide the comparison as a free function then the compiler will apply the same conversion rules on both sides of the == and the code will compile and work properly.

In general, the same applies to the rest of the operators (excluding operator[] and operator= that must be implemented as member functions). Using the free function version provides symmetry.